# Embedded Login, onLogin function not being called after successful login

Tags: login, embedded

I am implementing embedded login for a community. As far as I can tell the user is authenticated successfully, but after hitting the login button it does not call the onLogin function. If I understand the use, after hitting login, the page should refresh and the onLogin function should be called to update the page.

Here is my code. (I've masked the urls and secret)

embeded.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
   <head> 

    <title>FIX, curated coffee components</title>

    <!-- Some other metatags -->

    <meta name="salesforce-community" content="https://test.force.com/customers">
    <meta name="salesforce-client-id" content="test">
    <meta name="salesforce-redirect-uri" content="https://test/login/embed/_callback">
    <meta name="salesforce-mode" content="modal">
    <meta name="salesforce-mask-redirects" content="true">
    <meta name="salesforce-target" content="#sign-in-link">
    <meta name="salesforce-save-access-token" content="true">
    <meta name="salesforce-forgot-password-enabled" content="true">
    <meta name="salesforce-self-register-enabled" content="true">
    <meta name="salesforce-login-handler" content="onLogin">
    <meta name="salesforce-logout-handler" content="onLogout">



    <link href="https://test/servlet/servlet.loginwidgetcontroller?type=css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <script src="https://test/servlet/servlet.loginwidgetcontroller?type=javascript_widget&min=false" async defer></script>

    <script>
    function onLogin(identity) {
        console.log("hello");

        var targetDiv = document.querySelector(SFIDWidget.config.target);   
        var img = document.createElement('img'); 
        img.src = identity.photos.thumbnail; 
        img.className = "sfid-avatar";

        var username = document.createElement('span'); 
        username.innerHTML = identity.username;
        username.className = "sfid-avatar-name";

        var iddiv = document.createElement('div'); 
        iddiv.id = "sfid-identity";
        iddiv.appendChild(img);     
        iddiv.appendChild(username);        

        targetDiv.innerHTML = '';
        targetDiv.appendChild(iddiv);   
    }

    function onLogout() {
        SFIDWidget.init();
    }

    </script>


 </head>
 <body>
    <div id="sign-in-link" style  = "position: absolute; top:20px; right:20px;"></div>


 </body>


 </html>
```

_callback.html

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta name="salesforce-community" content="test">
    <meta name="salesforce-mode" content="inline-callback">
    <meta name="salesforce-save-access-token" content="true">
    <meta name="salesforce-allowed-domains" content="test.herokuapp.com">

    <script src="https://test/servlet/servlet.loginwidgetcontroller?type=javascipt_widget" async defer></script>
</head> 
<body></body>        
</html>
```

My webconsole output:

```
entering xauth retrieve function
servlet.loginwidgetcontroller?type=javascript_widget&min=false:575 XHR finished loading: GET "https://test/.well-known/auth-configuration".
setup @ servlet.loginwidgetcontroller?type=javascript_widget&min=false:575
handleXAuthMessages @ servlet.loginwidgetcontroller?type=javascript_widget&min=false:417
onMessage @ servlet.loginwidgetcontroller?type=javascript_widget&min=false:338
servlet.loginwidgetcontroller?type=javascript_widget&min=false:828 XHR finished loading: POST "https://test/servlet/servlet.loginwidgetcontroller?type=login".
authenticate @ servlet.loginwidgetcontroller?type=javascript_widget&min=false:828
onsubmit @ embed:1
frontdoor.jsp:1 Unrecognized Content-Security-Policy directive 'referrer'.

2SfdcSessionBase208.js:sourcemap:31 Unrecognized Content-Security-Policy directive 'referrer'.

b @ SfdcSessionBase208.js:sourcemap:31
updateAndActivate @ SfdcSessionBase208.js:sourcemap:33
e @ SfdcSessionBase208.js:sourcemap:36
t @ SfdcSessionBase208.js:sourcemap:7
SfdcFramework.b.require @ SfdcSessionBase208.js:sourcemap:21
(anonymous) @ SfdcSessionBase208.js:sourcemap:36
(anonymous) @ SfdcSessionBase208.js:sourcemap:36
sessionserver208.html:1 Unrecognized Content-Security-Policy directive 'referrer'.

RemoteAccessAuthorizationPage.apexp:1 Unrecognized Content-Security-Policy directive 'referrer'.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the error. There is a typo in the documentation for the callback function. They are missing an r in javascript.

```
<script src="https://test/servlet/servlet.loginwidgetcontroller?type=javascipt_widget" async defer></script>
```

has to be:

```
<script src="https://test/servlet/servlet.loginwidgetcontroller?type=javascript_widget" async defer></script>
```